# How to save something that I do on nifi.?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am new to apache NIFI. I was kind of wondering where is the save button. I tried a sample from a tutorial that I saw on youtube. I would like to save all the processors that I created for future reference. I don't see any save button. Is is possible to save my work open later.? Or open in another machine.?

Please Help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apache NiFi automatically saves your flow for you.  The flow configuration file is stored in `./conf/flow.xml.gz` by default.  NiFi also maintains an archive of previous versions in `./conf/archive`.  See the [Core Properties](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#core-properties-br) settings for changing these settings.  It is possible to backup and restore the flow configuration through these files.

Apache NiFi also has a [Templates](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#templates) feature that makes it easy to save a selection from your flow, export it from the UI, and share it with other NiFi installations.  Templates may be a closer approximation of a "save" button.

Comment: I am able to see all the files.And I also created template which I am able to view. Can you please tell me how to open them on NIFI's UI. I want to view the the processors.  When I try to open them all i can see is XML code.

Comment: NiFi runs one and only one flow configuration at a time, from flow.xml.gz by default.  You can backup and restore that file, or use it to recreate your flow on another machine.  But NiFi does not open/close arbitrary files, you just modify the running flow by manually making changes or deploying templates in your flow.

Comment: To create a minifi configuration, you are supposed to use nifi's gui.  Instructions:

Answer (score 5):

The Apache [Nifi Registry](https://nifi.apache.org/registry.html) is another option.  You can version processor groups, commit changes to the registry, revert back, add comments, etc.  I see it as similar to version control such as Git.  It's helpful in collaborative settings as well as promoting changes from development to production.